# Undefined value for address in react js

Tags: reactjs, function, components, solidity

I am trying to mint tokens to an address but I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="undefined", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.3.0) (argument="beneficiary", value="undefined", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)

I don't know the problem but I assume it has something to do with the input field when I enter the address. I have tried to pass the address as a string when I'm calling the function in my app.js but I got an error saying that is a BigInt and it won't read it as an address but rather as a number.I don't know if it has any relevance, but the function has role restriction as well.
in solidity, this is the mint function:

```
    function mint(address beneficiary, uint amount) onlyRole(ROLE_MINTER) whenNotPaused public returns(bool){
    require(hasRole(msg.sender, ROLE_MINTER), "Caller is not a minter");
    _mint(msg.sender, beneficiary, amount, "", "");
    return true;
}
```

And this is how I use it in my **app.js**:

```
mintTokens = (beneficiary,amount) => {
      this.setState({ loading: true })
      this.state.token.methods.mint(beneficiary,amount).send({ from:'0x45BA8CE241D23Bc364e32DCE9BbE5db0C2d48541' })
      .once('confirmation', (confirmation,info) => {
        this.loadBlockchainData()
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      })
        .on("error", (error) => {
          this.setState({ loading: false })
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

In the view, I created a form that would take the address input value of the beneficiary along with the amount and I pass the function to the onSubmit event.This is **Token.js:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
class Token extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          amount:'0',
          beneficiary: '',
          loading: false,
          mint_state:true,
          burn:false,
          pause:false,
          unpause:false,
          transfer:false,
          approve:false,
          transfer_from:false,
          send:false
        };
  
      }
     
      render(){
          if(this.state.mint_state)
          {
              return(
                <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={(event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    let beneficiary
                    let amount
                    beneficiary = this.input.value
                    amount =(this.input.value * 10 ** 18).toString()
                    this.props.mintTokens(beneficiary,amount)
                
                }}>
                    
                
                       <div className="full-width">
    <InputGroup size="sm" type="number" className="mb-3"   ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
    <InputGroup.Prepend >
      <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">To</InputGroup.Text>
   
    </InputGroup.Prepend>
    <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
  </InputGroup>
  
  <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3"  ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
    <InputGroup.Prepend>
      <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Amount</InputGroup.Text>
    </InputGroup.Prepend>
    <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
  </InputGroup>
  <div className="submit-button">
                  <div className="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" >Mint</button>
                      </div>
              </div>
  </div>
                      
                   
                    </form>
              )
          }
      }
}
export default Token;
```

I am new to react.js so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.I hope someone can point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work, though it is still throwing me an error, now it can read the values from the input. The problem was in the Token.js component. This is my working code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
class Token extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      beneficiary:'',
      amount:'0',
      input:'',
      mint_state: true,
      burn: false,
      pause: false,
      unpause: false,
      transfer: false,
      approve: false,
      transfer_from: false,
      send: false
    };

  }
 
  render() {
    if (this.state.mint_state) {
      return (
        <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          this.props.mintTokens(this.state.beneficiary, this.state.amount)

        }}>


          <div className="full-width">
            <InputGroup size="sm" type="number" className="mb-3"  value={this.state.beneficiary}   onChange={(event) => {
                        this.setState({beneficiary: event.target.value})
                      }} ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
              <InputGroup.Prepend >
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">To</InputGroup.Text>

              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
            </InputGroup>

            <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3" value={this.state.amount}   onChange={(event) => {
                        this.setState({amount: event.target.value})
                      }} ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Amount</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
            </InputGroup>
            <div className="submit-button">
              <div className="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" >Mint</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )
    }
  }
}
export default Token;
```